# Return a PowerShell array value based on the value of another

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a log file that I am trying parse through but haven't been able to find a solution.  I've copied a portion of the log file below.  Each group of 3 lines is one error.

```
csrak17 remove int_rpsmkt
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 add int_rpsops
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_rpssales
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_tpd
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_trpit
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
```

I am loading the log file into an array and have no problem returning a line with an error code.  What I need to do is first find a line with 'Error: HPDMG1064E' and then check the line two rows back to see if it has the word 'add' in it (like the second group example).

Is there a way to return a line in an array based on the value found in another?  Of course I will be looping through the file and repeating the process.

Here's what I have so far but it only returns one line to my output file for some reason.
Also, as you can see, I don't have any code for trying to find another index based on the current one.

```
$logs = Get-Content C:\Temp\test\ProdtamResults_HPDMG1064E_errors.doc
$Value = "HPDMG1064E"

foreach($log in $logs) {
    $i = 0
    while ($i -le $logs.length-1) {

        if ($logs[$i] -match $Value)
            {
                return $logs[$i] | out-file C:\Temp\test\results.txt
            }
    $i++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try

```
$logs = Get-Content C:\Temp\test\ProdtamResults_HPDMG1064E_errors.doc
$Value = "HPDMG1064E"

gc $logs | select-string -Pattern $value -Context 3 | 
? { $_.context.precontext[1] -match '\sadd\s' } | select linenumber, line
```

This return a `psobject[]`  with the line number and the line value of your needed match.

Comment: @Neolisk The magic of  `MatchInfo` type returned by `select-string` ;). Thanks

Comment: Thanks C.B.!  Nice elegant solution.  I actually removed the 'select linenumber..' piece and am able to work with those results.

Comment: I didn't know about -context, very useful, here's some more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/05/07/select-string-context.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reduced test case, it will output i-th line when (i-2)th line contains "add":

```
$file = @"
csrak17 remove int_rpsmkt
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 add int_rpsops
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_rpssales
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_tpd
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
csrak17 remove int_trpit
Could not perform the administration request
Error: HPDMG1064E   The group member was not found. (status 0x14c01428)
"@;

$lines = $file -split "`n"

$Value = "HPDMG1064E";
for($i=0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++) {
  if($lines[$i] -match "HPDMG1064E") {
    if($lines[$i-2] -match "add") {
      Write-Host $lines[$i]; #or do something else
    }
  }
}
```

In your code `Get-Content` will have it already split by newline, so you don't have to do it.